# Web extension/plugin or browser feature to detect page size (or page bloat)

Tags: chrome, web-browser

I am done with morbidly bloated websites that consume too much bandwidth. Especially now, I am trying to save internet data so I always try to choose carefully which site to visit when doing a search in Google. Long ago, Google has displayed the estimated page size in Search results. Now, it is gone.

As far as I know, the closest feature that I have seen was on Vivaldi browser, but it simply shows the size of the page as it is loading. What I would want is to see the total page size so that I can decide if I should visit the page or not. Are there any browser (preferably Chrome or Opera) features/plugins/extensions that would allow me to identify the page size in a Google search result?

Comment: I do not think that knowing the page size is very useful anymore nowadays... because of both all the multimedia content that needs to be downloaded too, and also all javascript parts that both add sizes because of the javascript itself (which is not always slim) and whatever data it pulls out. It is then very hard to predict how much bandwidth a site will require. You can at least start to browse it with all javascript deactivated (various plugins for browsers) and enable selectively. Or be more radical and use a text based browser like lynx/links.